# Add HTML markups dynamically in a JSON file with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I would love to put HTML markups (created dynamically by a CMS) in a JSON file.

I know that I have to escape double quotes in the html string by adding "" like below.

```
{
    "title": "Title",
    "data": "<main id=\"container\"><div class=\"my-class\">My data created my ProcessWire templates</div></main>"
}
```

But I don't know how to do it dynamically.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. Put the HTML string in an array and call `json_encode()`. It will escape the quotes automatically.

Comment: Simple as hell. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build an array with the elements you want.  For the example you have:

```
$htmlMarkup = [
    "title" => 'Title',
    "data" => '<main id="container"><div class="my-class">My data created my ProcessWire templates</div></main>'
];

json_encode($htmlMarkup);
```

Notice to build the strings, I just used single quotes.  If you are building the strings dynamically, this probably doesn't matter.